# Angular 2 import issue: "Zone already exported on window the object!"

Tags: angular, systemjs, jspm

I started to play with angular2, and when trying to create a component with a dependency on angular that is located in its parent location, e.g.,

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, For} from '../../ext_components/angular2/angular2.dev';
```

I get the following error message:

> Zone already exported on window the object!

Could someone please explain what causes this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: is this your only import?

Comment: Try referencing angular2 without the path specification: `import { ... } from 'angular2/angular2`

Comment: @Braim, I import these components (e.g., `import {Component, View, bootstrap, For} from '../../ext_components/angular2/angular2.dev';
`) in the `app.ts` (located at the root), as well as in another `file.ts` located in a child directory

Comment: @Brocco, tried, but in vain...